# appending detached div within a funtction

Tags: jquery, append, detach

I am trying to re-append some div´s after detaching but it is not working for hours now...i can´t find my mistake...

Sitution:

There is an input field with a livesearch function ( onkeydown ).. 
On the function i am querying for some data. lets say my orginal page without livesearch has got 2 divs:

`div id="a"` and `div id="b"`

after the livesearch there is one more `div id="c"`...

I only want to display the id="c" but keep the id="a" and id="b" ( but not showing them to the user) .. I can not user hide() and show() because this will damage the applications on the div´s..

I tried to use detach and appendTo.. The code is close to working .. but not 100% ..

I am wrapping the old divs into a  class called old_div

All the new livesearch results get the class of livesearch_results

---

```
function livesearch(value){

 var kasten = $('.original_div');

// first keydown

if($('.old_div').length == 0 && $('.livesearch_result').length == 0 ){

   kasten.addClass('old_div');

var detached = $('.old_div').detach();      


}

.... do the livesearch ... everything works fine ... but 

if(value == ""){

$('.livesearch_result').remove();

detached.appendTo("#rechteSeite");

return;

}

___________________________________________
```

as it is a function it is calling an undefined variable detached if value == ""

... so to make that clear..everything works till the point where value == "" .. i just can not find a way to re append the old div id="a" and "b" , because the variable is undefined. within the function(on keypress)... declaring it again within this function is not working coz .old_div allready had been detached on the first keydown ... i really would appreciate some advice on that..

of corse its possible to suggest a different solution .. it s not compulsory to think only of detach and append .. but i am out of thoughts here:/
thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

If everything else is correct, your immediate problem would be fixed by making 'detached' a global variable.

Declare it outside the function, or access it as window.detached.